# GPS capable rangefinders or cameras that can capture lat / long data from a distance?

Tags: gps

Anyone have experience using this technology?
i.e. field verifications of structures where you need to capture the lat / long of a house that is 1000 feet from the road with limited access.

Answer (score 4):

Actually a pretty simplistic application of offset that was implemented early in the commercial GPS era by Trimble and Laser Atlanta.

Check out Laser Atlanta's "Advantage" [line](http://www.laseratlanta.com/la_advantage_ci.html), or LTI's  TruePulse [line](http://www.lasertech.com/TruPulse-Laser-Rangefinder.aspx). The resulting az/elev/slope distance string provides "offset" from the GPS position collected at the laser head. Using offset the sample point position can be calculated in near real time with a hand held data logger. Or, the "offset" and GPS position can be combined and corrected after collection for more precise results.

Trimble's Pathfinder Office and TerraSync software packages excel at this processing flow.

Answer (score 2):

This is a cheap alternative:

> Theodolite HD includes the ability to take geo-stamped and geo-tagged
>   photos and screenshots from the app, with 2X and 4X zoom, buffered
>   background image saves, plus an option to write custom notes on
>   photos. The app has an integrated map with standard satellite, and
>   hybrid views. Optical-mechanical calibration lets you correct any
>   offsets in gyro, accelerometer, and camera hardware. In addition, the
>   app includes a zero angle reference mode, an A-B Calculator for
>   height, distance, heading, position, and angles, e-mail data export
>   with KML, clipboard integration, %grade display, optical rangefinders,
>   mils, night vision lens filters, and MGRS, UTM, and four lat/lon
>   formats. Theodolite HD is feature equivalent to Theodolite Pro for
>   iPhone, but contains a layout and interface scale that takes advantage
>   of the iPad's larger screen.

[image]

http://www.hrtapps.com/theodolitehd/

$4 plus cost of ipad.

Comment: How accurate could that be, seeing as how you don't have a tripod or anything?