# GPS capable rangefinder or camera to capture GPS data

Tags: gps, camera-class

I have looked at this link [GPS capable rangefinders or cameras that can capture lat / long data from a distance?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14236/gps-capable-rangefinders-or-cameras-that-can-capture-lat-long-data-from-a-dist)

I have looked into the [LaserTech](https://lasertech.com/) product information but it seems to me I can't find a product which output the GPS data.
The GPS data should be read into a computer. The communication can be any hardware protocol or USB (plug and play).
The distance is irrelevant it can be up to 5 meter or more or less
The communication with the device (the device which capture the GPS location for an object) can be via Bluetooth or  USB or UART or SPI or any communication port or wifi.
I want the data (GSP data) to be capture into a computer with a frequency can be any or manual hit; for example, if I press a button on the device, it capture the GPS data for the target( a tree)

The budget is up to $2000.

I would like to see integration manual for the product if possible. EU
companies are better to deal with or UK based also
Any further details, please let me know.

Comment: Trimble is in Europe https://help.trimblegeospatial.com/TerraFlex/Laser-rangefinders.htm and so is Riegl http://www.riegl.com/products/laser-distance-meters/ these are very high end equipment with high precision, perhaps a cheaper model would suit your needs (Bushnell for example https://www.google.com/search?q=bushnell+hybrid+laser+rangefinder+gps). There are cameras that record GPS location but it will be the *location of the camera* and *not the target* (GoPro for example https://community.gopro.com/s/article/how-to-use-gps-performance-stickers?language=en_US).

Comment: I have contacted Bushnell since I am looking to capture the data into a computer not from screen. Any more details of a product would be great . Like UART or SPI  communication or any communication for the capture data into a computer via USB (plug and play)

Comment: You're more likely to get suggestions if you describe what you are trying to do.  For example: 
 How far away will your target be?  Are you trying to use a single Distance + Bearing or can you use a distance / distance  workflow?  Can you use Bluetooth?  What budget do you have?

Comment: @Trams
 Many thanks for your guideness.  will Refine the question as per your suggestion

Comment: Another question - what accuracy are you hoping to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be wonderful if there was a handheld laser rangefinder (something like a TruPulse 360) which also included a GNSS receiver and which did all the necessary calculations to spit out a target Lat / Long / Alt.  Sadly I don't know of anything which does this.

Here's an **expensive and no-longer-available Trimble-centric solution** - I've used this extensively:

You could use a Geo7x data collector with the laser rangefinder accessory.  Run TerraSync on the data collector, do real-time corrections to get GNSS accuracy as good as you want (5M or sub-meter or sub-foot or cm-level, depending on how much you spend).  The Rangefinder gives distances with good accuracy (a couple of cm) with useful distance range from 1M to about 100M.  TerraSync on the Geo7x calculates the location of the rangefinder target and transfers target data to Pathfinder Office on PC, from there you can output a wide variety of formats.

Practically there are a few problems with this.

- You can't buy Geo 7x with Rangefinder accessory anymore (unless you pick up a second-hand unit)
- You can't buy TerraSync or Pathfinder Office anymore (and they were expensive)
- This solution would cost much more than your budget

Doing some **Internet research gives various solutions**:

- The EOS solution here is one: https://eos-gnss.com/knowledge-base/eos-laser-mapping-choose-your-gps-workflow
- The Trimble TerraFlex solution works with LTI Laser Rangefinders - look through the posts on this forum for some links: https://community.trimble.com/communities/community-homepage/digestviewer/viewthread?GroupId=811&MID=31127&CommunityKey=2724bc18-0fbe-4f63-a41c-4a5fa6264382

I have not looked at either of these in detail, but they will cost more than your budget - EOS wants ESRI Software which is not cheap, Trimble wants TerraFlex which is subscription-based, and a TruPulse 360 is likely to cost over $1500.

So finally we go to **the budget option** - Windows-based because that's what I know.

- Take a Windows laptop / tablet which has a built-in GNSS
- Buy a laser rangefinder which has Bluetooth and heading sensor
- Pair the Tablet with the Rangefinder
- Run your favourite terminal application (PuTTY, Hyperterm, etc) and connect to the serial port associated with the Rangefinder
- Every time you take a rangefinder measurement, I expect the terminal program will display a NMEA sentence with distance and bearing (described below)
- Get the location from the internal GNSS (Windows devices with GNSS often have a serial port which gives NMEA GGA sentence which contains Latitude, Longitude, altitude).
- Simple maths gives the target Lat and Long using the GNSS position and rangefinder distance and bearing (don't forget to take magnetic declination into account)

This also has issues:

- The internal GNSS in tablets will typically have low-grade GNSS. Expect errors of 3 to 5M.
- You have some calculations to do.

Some important general information on rangefinder workflows:

- If you use Distance / Bearing offset to a feature (that's the easiest since it's a single measurement), the position error is Range * TAN(BearingError), so at 10M range with a bearing error of 3° you'll get a feature error of 0.5M (plus your GNSS error).  If you go out to 100M, the error is 5M (plus GNSS error).
- If you use distance / distance offset workflow, which takes distance measurements from 2 different positions, the feature position accuracy is typically better than 10cm (plus GNSS error).

Explanation of Laser Rangefinder NMEA output:

```
$PTNLA,HV,8.89,M,148.6,D,4.85,D,8.92,M*4D
(Sample from Trimble LaserAce 1000, other laser rangefinders give similar msentences)
$ : "Standard" NMEA delimeter, indicates the start of a NMEA sentence
PTNLA : Proprietary Trimble LA sentence (same format as LA sentences from other suppliers)
HV : (not sure what this means)
8.89, M : Horizontal range to target in meters
148.6,D : Bearing to target in degrees
4.85,D : Elevation angle to target in degrees
8.92,M : Slant range to target in meters
*4D : Checksum
```